# How do I have to escape ampersands in URLs when logging in with OpenID?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

Well actually I know, that I should replace & by %26

But I'm using this URL to log in with OpenID:

https://innubili-gidea.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=icada.com&continue=https://innubili-gidea.appspot.com/%3Fdomain%3Dicada.com%26campaign%3D2%26

[image: Login Link]

As you can see, the continue parameter is properly escaped.

But after being redirected through Googles login pages, it redirects me back to

https://innubili-gidea.appspot.com/?domain=icada.com

So the `&campaign=2` parameter is missing

[image: Link after Login]

Can you confirm, that I escaped the continue parameter correctly?

For then it looks to me as this seems to be an issue at Googles login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly escaping the Url, and yes, this is a well-known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3249&q=openid&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).

Answer (score 3):

I just found out it works, if I escape the ampersand twice.

```
& -> %26 -> %2526
```